# What are the benefits of cloud load balancer when using managed Kubernetes in the cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cloud, load-balancing

I'm currently working on Kubernetes in the cloud, and I'm using nginx-ingress to load balancer and manage how traffic gets to my services. I see that many people are using cloud load balancers for advanced stuff like multi-region load balancing but I still don't understand how they fit in the picture.

So my questions is What are the benefits of cloud load balancer when using Kubernetes in the cloud with nginx-ingress ?
Don't they do the same thing?

Comment: Keep in mind SO is focused in programming question. In addition, only ine question per post should be asked. You may to ask this in ServerFault

Comment: Sorry, I reduced the number of questions to focus only on the difference between cloud load balancer and kubernetes-ingress and the question is still related to Stackoverflow topic and many people are wondering about this issue and the utility of the cloud load balancers in k8s. I would really appreciate it if you could help. Thank you

Comment: It's a design choice. If you use NGINX ingress, you still have a load balancer in front of your cluster, at least in front of your NGINX ingress pods. It's a normal gateway to connect the outside world. You don't explicitly request for a LB but GKE deploy and configure it for you!

Comment: Yes, even if GKE configures it for me, i still have to configure some routing rules and other things. And configuring Nginx-ingress is not that hard. So are there any benefits of using cloud LB for the cluster ingress instead of a nginx-ingress ?